# Using dictionary and cursors to calculate a field based on values from another table - KeyError [0]

Tags: arcpy, cursor, dictionary

I'm new to dictionaries and am still a Python beginner. I'm trying to update field(s) based off of field values in another table using the OID field as a key. The search cursor dictionary has been filtered down (in an effort to conditionally update the values in the `Line_Count_13_8 field`) with a `where` clause for the portion of the script where I am receiving an error. I am getting:

> KeyError: [0] error

on this line:

```
if search_feats_138[0] == upd_row[0]:
```

Here is the whole block:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import time
start = time.time()
print start
print "Start"
arcpy.env.OverwriteOutput = True

subLayer='C:\Topo_Check_Tess_V5.gdb\Sub'
transLayer='C:\Topo_Check_Tess_V5.gdb\TL'
ppLayer='C:\Topo_Check_Tess_V5.gdb\PP'

pp_trans_GUJoin ='C:\Topo_Check_Tess_V5.gdb\pp_trans_GU_SpatialJoin'

SubLayer_pp_trans_GUJoin = 'C:\Topo_Check_Tess_V5.gdb\SubLayer_pp_trans_GUSpatialJoin'

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis ("SubLayer_Layer", "pp_trans_GUJoin_Layer", SubLayer_pp_trans_GUJoin, 'JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE', 'KEEP_ALL', fieldMappings, 'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE', .000002)
```

**THIS SECTION WORKS**

```
#add in Line_Count field 
arcpy.AddField_management(subLayer, "Line_Count", "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

search_feats = {f[0]:f[1] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(SubLayer_pp_trans_GUJoin,["OBJECTID","Join_Count"])}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(subLayer,["OBJECTID","Line_Count"]) as upd_cur:
    for upd_row in upd_cur:
        upd_row[1] = search_feats[upd_row[0]]
        upd_cur.updateRow(upd_row)
    print "Line_Counts Updated"
del upd_cur
```

**THIS SECTION DOES NOT WORK - KeyError: [0]**

```
#add in Line_Count_13_8 field
arcpy.AddField_management(subLayer, "Line_Count_13_8", "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

#where clause
where_13_8 = ' "VT" = 13.8 '

#arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(SubLayer_pp_trans_GUJoin, "Sub_PP_Trans_Join_13_8", where_13_8)

search_feats_13_8 = {f[0]:f[1] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(SubLayer_pp_trans_GUJoin,["OBJECTID","Join_Count"], where_13_8)}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(subLayer,["OBJECTID","Line_Count_13_8"]) as upd_cur:
    for upd_row in upd_cur:
        if search_feats_13_8[0] == upd_row[0]:
            upd_row[1] = search_feats_13_8[upd_row[0]]
        else: 
            upd_row[1] = 0
        upd_cur.updateRow(upd_row)    
    print "Line_Count_13.8 Updated"
del upd_curl

end = time.time()
print (end - start)/60
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`search_feats_13_8` is a dict with `OBJECTID` as the key (part between `[]`).  `upd_row` is a tuple where the first element (referenced with `[0]`) is `OBJECTID`:

What is being attempted here is to see if `search_feats_13_8` contains the `OBJECTID` and if so, then update the row.

#### So what's Wrong?

This attempts to use `[0]` to lookup a value in the `search_feats_13_8` `dict`, but that is not the key to the `dict`.

```
if search_feats_13_8[0] == upd_row[0]:
    upd_row[1] = search_feats_13_8[upd_row[0]]
else: 
    upd_row[1] = 0
```

#### How to Fix:

The code should likely be:

```
if upd_row[0] in search_feats_13_8:
    upd_row[1] = search_feats_13_8[upd_row[0]]
else: 
    upd_row[1] = 0
```

This tests if the `OBJECTID` in `upd_row[0]` is preset in the `dict` `search_feats_13_8`, and if it is, uses the value to update the row.  If it is not present (the else) then set the value to `0`.

#### But even better would be:

```
upd_row[1] = search_feats_13_8.get(upd_row[0], 0)
```

This does the above in one line.  It use the [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method to lookup the `OBJECTID` in the dict and return it if present, otherwise return `0`.